# pyspark sql avg returns non-zero value averaging 0 and null values

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running the code below in pyspark.  In the code below I am creating the final product_cycle_days field by taking the average of the product_cycle_days field from the sub query, grouped by several fields.  The issue I'm having is that if I look at the unaggregated sub query the only values for product_cycle_days are 0 or null, but in the final query a value of 0.5 is returned after it's averaged.

I'm translating this code from a postgresql source, and in the postgresql source a value of 0 is returned in the final query.  so I'm trying to figure out why pyspark-sql is returning 0.5.

I've included the whole query and result below.  I've also included just the results from the sub query below that.

code:

```
product_repeat_query="""select
        dateclosed, storeid, brandname, producttype, productsubtype, size, product_id,
        sum(product_repeat_gross) + (rand()/10000) as product_repeat_gross, avg(product_cycle_days) as product_cycle_days
    from
        (
        select
            dateclosed, t.product_id, t.storeid, t.producttype, t.productsubtype, t.size, t.brandname,
            case
                when ticketid = first_value(ticketid) over (partition by t.product_id, customer_uuid
            ORDER BY
                dateclosed ASC rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) then 0
                else grossreceipts
            end as product_repeat_gross, datediff(dateclosed,
            lag(dateclosed, 1) over (partition by t.brandname, customer_uuid, t.product_id
        ORDER BY
            dateclosed ASC )
            ) as product_cycle_days
        from
            t )
    group by
        dateclosed, brandname, producttype, productsubtype, size, storeid, product_id"""


product_repeat=spark.sql(product_repeat_query)


product_repeat[(product_repeat['dateclosed']=='2020-01-02')\
               &(product_repeat['brandname']=='LABS')\
               &(product_repeat['producttype']=='SHIRT')\
              &(product_repeat['productsubtype']=='PREPACK')\
              &(product_repeat['size']=='XL')\
              &(product_repeat['storeid']==105)\
              &(product_repeat['product_id']=='c43a1a06-6a63-46ba-a476-xxxxxxxxxxx')]\
.show(truncate=False)
```

output:

```
+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+----+------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|dateclosed|storeid|brandname|producttype|productsubtype|size|product_id                          |product_repeat_gross|product_cycle_days|
+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+----+------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|2020-01-02|105    |LABS  |SHIRT     |PREPACK       |XL|c43a1a06-6a63-46ba-a476-xxxxxxxxxxx|3.464462313624555E-5|0.5          |
+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+----+------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

subquery:

```
sub_query="""select
            dateclosed, t.product_id, t.storeid, t.producttype, t.productsubtype, t.size, t.brandname,
            case
                when ticketid = first_value(ticketid) over (partition by t.product_id, customer_uuid
            ORDER BY
                dateclosed ASC rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) then 0
                else grossreceipts
            end as product_repeat_gross, datediff(dateclosed,
            lag(dateclosed, 1) over (partition by t.brandname, customer_uuid, t.product_id
        ORDER BY
            dateclosed ASC )
            ) as product_cycle_days
        from
            t
        where dateclosed='2020-01-02'
        and brandname='LABS'
        and producttype='SHIRT'
        and productsubtype='PREPACK'
        and size='XL'
        and storeid=105
        and product_id='c43a1a06-6a63-46ba-a476-xxxxxxxxxxx'"""

sub=spark.sql(sub_query)

sub.show(truncate=False)


+----------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+--------------+----+------------+--------------------+------------------+
|dateclosed|product_id                          |storeid|producttype|productsubtype|size|brandname|product_repeat_gross|product_cycle_days|
+----------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+--------------+----+------------+--------------------+------------------+
|2020-01-02|c43a1a06-6a63-46ba-a476-xxxxxxxxxxx|105    |SHIRT     |PREPACK       |XL|LABS  |0.0                 |null              |
|2020-01-02|c43a1a06-6a63-46ba-a476-xxxxxxxxxxx|105    |SHIRT     |PREPACK       |XL|LABS  |0.0                 |0                 |
|2020-01-02|c43a1a06-6a63-46ba-a476-xxxxxxxxxxx|105    |SHIRT     |PREPACK       |XL|LABS  |0.0                 |null              |
+----------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+--------------+----+------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi. Just wondering why there is + (rand()/10000)?  Most likely not relevant, but I can't wrap my had around it. Sorr, just interested.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to explain your problem. There is too much unnecessary details in your query. Please only keep a **minimal** amount of code to illustrate your problem.